# Delta<T> in PATCH actions not tracking primitive types

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm using Delta for patching an entity as outlined in "Partial Updates(PATCH request)" section outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx)
I have the following ProductDTO:

```
 public class ProductDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [UIHint("Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And the following action method defined:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Patch(int id, Delta<ProductDTO> delta)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

If I pass in the following JSON (via Fiddler using the PATCH verb)

```
{"ID":1,"Name":"test","Price":"1000"}
```

The "delta" in the action method contains only the "Name" property and not the ID and Price  properties. It appears that the delta is not containing values of types "int","decimal" and primitive types in general.

What am I missing here?

TIA

**EDIT**: Here is a [link](https://github.com/abpatel/aspnetwebstack/commit/9311c53ff475611da54aa112402bbd47797bc5a0) to a modded version of Delta that includes support for primitive JSON data types. Comments appreciated

Comment: Does your controller derive from ODataController or EntitySetController? Delta<T> is *not* supported for non-OData formatters.

Comment: My controller derives from the standard ApiController

Comment: I have partial Odata support in my actions by using ODataQueryOptions in my action methods like so: [GET("Products", RouteName = "GetAllProducts")] public ProductDTO[] Get(ODataQueryOptions options) { return new ProductDTO[] { }; } If Delta<T> is NOT supported, is there any other way to make PATCH requests work? Clearly having a full blown OData controller should not be a pre-requisite for being able to implement a PATCH.

Comment: Was a workaround ever found for this?

Comment: Does it work if you change your JSON to {"ID": 1, "Name": "test", "Price": 1000 } - i.e. remove the quotes from the value of Price?