# Implementing PATCH with Delta<T> with JSON Formatter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have installed the OData library, but only to gain access to Delta for making PATCH usable for WebAPI. It is kinda working, but not for types like decimal and int. I understand this is due to the JSON Formatter, and not specifically Delta but is there a workaround or a fix (or workaround) that can be applied to this to get it to work.

I know Delta was made to work with OData (and the formatter), but without something like Delta using PATCH without Delta become a difficult thing to implement, when you are allowing partial updates of a resource and do not restrict the fields that can be passed.

Is there an alternative out there?

**Related Question - have the same issue, int/decimal etc. don't update**

[Delta<T> in PATCH actions not tracking primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561874/deltat-in-patch-actions-not-tracking-primitive-types)

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE SOME CODE FOR CONTEXT**

The POST/PATCH/PUT Types will be simplified to specific DTOs so that i can reduce the noise of the objects but for now i am using my Model objects directly as i was just trying ot get it working.

**PATCH Route**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Patch(int id, Delta<Measurement> measurement)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var dbMeasurement = (from n in _repo.Include("SurveyItem")
                      where n.Id == id
                      select n).SingleOrDefault();

        measurement.Patch(dbMeasurement);
        _uow.Commit();

        var measurementRep = dbMeasurement.ToRepresentation<Measurement, MeasurementRepresentation>();
        resp.Content = new ObjectContent<MeasurementRepresentation>(measurementRep, new JsonHalMediaTypeFormatter());

        return resp;
    }
```

**FIDDLER POST OPTIONS**

*Headers*

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:1996
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/json
```

*Body*

```
{
     "Value":101.00
}
```

a 200 is returned but nothing is updated.but what is more telling is the following, value is 0:

[image: Delta]

I can persist strings, just no other types.

Comment: What version of the OData package are you using? I can successfully patch integers with the 5.0 beta 2 (confirmed) and 4.0.30506 (recollection, quite sure though).

Comment: 5.0 Beta 2.... i can patch, but it seems strings only, int, decimal etc do not get patched. I am using the JSON formatter, are you using the same?

Comment: I am, actually. What happens if you check the validity of the ModelState in the PATCH method? Does it get rejected if you try to patch non-strings?

Comment: Hi Kazu, nothing gets rejected, it simply is a case of the non string values not being persisted in the Delta, it is very odd, i.e. you pass them but in the delta when you check the values they are null for non strings.

Comment: Very strange indeed. The fact that you can actually check the Delta means that the ModelState is valid (otherwise patch would just be null). I guess that as a final resort you could post all relevant code? The method and model perhaps? That way, maybe I can try to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since commenting is getting a bit out of hand, I'm starting this answer.

I've tried your code, and am seeing a few odd things:

First of all, you don't use override on the Patch method. Without this, the request shouldn't even arrive because it cannot be resolved.

Secondly, assuming that your 'Value' field is of type decimal, I cannot send a decimal like you do. I.e. in a JSON with just the value of 101.00. This is something I've also noticed in my own application, and my solution is to send it as a string, encapsulating it in quotes ("Value": "101.00"). It is still parsed as a decimal this way, and I'm guessing that the same holds for doubles and floats.

Finally, in order to really exhaust all options, can you include this line of code in the top of your patch method?

```cs
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState));
}
```

This way, you get a proper 400 BadRequest response with a response of what's wrong.

Still, with all of the above included, I can still patch non-strings. Visual Studio already starts nagging about my first point, if you don't override the method it mentions hidden methods. I hope that one of these points will solve your problem. If not, I will update my answer with hopefully more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative out there?

Yes, with Asp.Net core use `JsonPatchDocument` (using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch)

[Here is how to use it](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-json-patch-partial-api-updates)