# Cannot access a disposed object while reading the Http response content object for failed scenarios

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpresponse, bad-request

I am observing "***Cannot access a disposed object***." error while trying to read the response content for the failure scenarios. I am getting these failures in my UTwhen passing BAD_REQUEST as a mocked response.

```
 Test method 
    UnitTests.Tests.Test_BadResponse threw exception: 
    System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.
  Stack Trace: 
    HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
    HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

The snippet of a mocked object.

```
ShimHttpClientWrapper.AllInstances.SendHttpRequestHttpClientWrapperHttpRequestTypeStringStringString =
                    (instance, req_type, api, authtoken, requestBody) =>
                    {
                        return new HttpResponseMessage
                        {
                            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                            Content = "SomeContent"
                        };
                    };
```

Please note: the following is passing when I am using HTTPResponse.Ok in the mocked object.
My code is as follows,

```
try{
    response = ServiceClient.SendHttpRequestWithRetries(
                        HttpClientWrapper.HttpRequestType.HTTP_POST,
                        someEndpoint,
                        someToken,
                        requestBody.ToString());
    
                    var asyncResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    asyncResponse.Wait();
                    responseBody = asyncResponse.Result;
                    // If the response is from 200; then it will go to next otherwise error handling under catch
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
            catch (HttpRequestException err)
            {
                Logger.LogWarning($"Api: Failed to work for the Action. [StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}, Details: {err.Message}]");
                throw new InternalError_Exception(false, GetErrorString(responseBody), (int)response.StatusCode);
            }
```

Specifically the error is coming from ,

```
var asyncResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Calls to HttpContent ReadAsAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942514/multiple-calls-to-httpcontent-readasasync)

Comment: What about `var asyncResponse = response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: That won't give the exception but won't help me understand why my object is getting disposed of, that too only for BAD_REQUEST scenarios

Comment: @Sasha, I don't think, the scenarios are related. I am not calling the Async twice. its the failure scenario only

Comment: I think the response got read twice effectively. The first read can happen within a framework or a toolset you are using (e.g. `OneCertServiceClient`) and the second one in your code. How to fix the issue depends on what exactly is `OneCertServiceClient.SendHttpRequestWithRetries`. Is it your code as well? Can you modify it?

Comment: @Sasha, thanks for looking into it. The OneCertClient Code is my abstraction on there HTTP retries and I am not doing any content read there, further, if it was issue with the reading it twice then it should have failed for success scenarios as well, what do you think?

Comment: Would you mind providing relevant code of the `OneCertClient` class? So we have a complete picture of what is happening