# cast httpResponse to ResposeEntity is null C#

Tags: c#, httpresponse

I have this code:

```
private class TResponse
{
  public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
  public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(methodName, data).Result;
TResponse result = default(TResponse);
var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
if (responseString.CompareTo("null") != 0)
result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>().Result;
```

in this code result is null. but if I write this in other way result will have a value!:

```
var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseContent.Result.ToString());
```

Why First code is not working? I used that for so many Entity types but for TResponse is is not working.

response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() returns "{"IsSuccessful":false,"ErrorCode":"8","ErrorMessage":"XXXXXXxxxxssssss."}"

Comment: I think there is no need to have `ReadAsStringAsync` when you are using `ReadAsAsync`. And possible this is linked/duplicate with [@Peter's answer on Multiple Calls to HttpContent ReadAsAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26942711/8017690), requiring resetting the stream to `Position = 0` when reading again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting an asynchronous task. This is what th **Async** suggests in the name of `ReadAsAsync`. So, you are running it without waiting for it to complete, which allows your program to fulfill other operations while waiting for the result. But you also try to infer the result of the operation, before it's completed. If you want to sync the call with the result, you can `await` for it, like

```
result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>();
```

Read more here: https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/async-await/RSPEC-3168/

Comment: Hmmm, I think if you change it to async, the `.Result` should be removed: `result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>()`. What the Post owner tries to do is call the async method synchronously, that is why `.Result` is needed: `<Task>.Result`.

Comment: @YongShun thanks for pointing that out! It seems that it's been a long while since I last worked with C#. Thanks again!